# Encapsulate Lazy<T>

Tags: c#

After a number of times I need to implement a `Lazy<T>` pattern, it came to my mind the idea to put the whole pattern into a class in order to hide Lazy implementation.

In the case of "Loading a singleton configuration object for my services", I did something like this:

```
public interface IConfigurationProvider<T>
{
    T GetConfiguration();
}

public abstract class SingletonConfigurationProvider<TConfiguration> : IConfigurationProvider<TConfiguration>
{
    private static readonly Lazy<TConfiguration> _lazy =
       new Lazy<TConfiguration>(_loadConfiguration);

    private static Func<TConfiguration> _loadConfiguration;

    private SingletonConfigurationProvider() { }
    public SingletonConfigurationProvider(Func<TConfiguration> LoadConfig)
    {
        _loadConfiguration = LoadConfig;
    }

    public TConfiguration GetConfiguration()
    {
        return _lazy.Value;
    }
}
```

My goal is to obtain, from the "outside" the simplicity in doing this:

```
public class ConfigTest : SingletonConfigurationProvider<ObjectTest> 
{
    public ConfigTest()
        : base(Load)
    {
    }

    public static ObjectTest Load()
    {
        return new ObjectTest()
        {
            testInt = 3,
            testString = "Hi"
        };
    }
}
```

The points are:

- It compiles but it breaks at runtime, with "TypeInitialization Exception" saying that `_loadConfiguration` couldn't be null. Is it because the lazy is being constructed before the `SingletonConfigurationProvider` constructor?
- Is it possible to achieve what I want without breaking the semantic of singleton?

Comment: You are basically constructing an abstraction around 2 lines of code: static field and getter. Is it really worth it?

Comment: The problem might be in the first line where you initialize _lazy when _loadConfiguration is null. Try moving initialization to your overloaded constructor.

Comment: @Sarathy In that case _lazy couldn't be readonly

Comment: _lazy could be readonly but not static. Sorry I missed out that static declaration.

Comment: @Sarathy Which would mean that it would not be a singleton anymore.

Comment: @Maarten It doesn't really matter, the initialization is still done when the delegate is null. Changing the delegate after this does not change the lazy object.

Comment: Yes you are right @Maarten. This one is tricky.

Comment: The whole design is flawed, if it is supposed to be a singleton then why does it have a public constructor where you can supply where it gets the value from?

Comment: Initialize it with new Lazy<TConfiguration>( () => _loadConfiguration() );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abstraction you're looking for is a *memoising function*. In this kind of function, you modify the getter function so that it implements an 'execute-it-only-once' kind of pattern. Untested code but roughly;

```
public Func<T> Memoize(Func<T> slowFunction) {
    bool evaluated = false;
    T value = default(T);

    return () => {
        if (!evaluated) {
            value = slowFunction();
            evaluated = true;
        }

        return value;
    };
}
```

So you now have a function which you can use like this;

```
Func<TConfiguration> onceOnlyLoad = Memoise(Load);
```

Now you can call `onceOnlyLoad()` as many times as you like and it'll only load the config first time you call it.

If you want, you can use `Lazy<T>` internally to giv the same behaviour. Up to you.